# 4-bit adder-subtractor logic

Tags: logic, vhdl, addition, subtraction

I have almost successfully implemented n-bit adder-subtractor. It works fine, except for one thing.

Carry after an unsigned subtraction doesn't behave, how i expected.

[Here](http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~ehwang/digitaldesign/contents/04%20Combinational%20Components.pdf) is on page 11 the circuit which i have build. In my opinion i have build it the right way. It is a 4-bit adder/subtractor.

So to understand my troubles with the unsigned carry let's calculate 1111 - 1111 in unsigned. Well 15 - 15 is 0, so it should be 0000. What is the unsigned carry?

Input:

```
a <= "1111";
b <= "1111";
s <= '1';
```

The only thing s does, is building a 2's complement of b. Let's do it.

```
b = 1111
1'st complement
b = 0000
2's complement
b = 0001
```

Now we can perform an addition 1111 + 0001.

```
 1111
 0001
=====
10000
```

And right here is my (thought) problem. The carry (the 5'th bit) is 1. I have calculated 15-15 = 0 with an overflow carry, which i don't understand at all.

On the other hand, i can calculate 1110 - 1111  (14-15) which should be -1, which can't be represented with unsigned numbers. So here i would expect an overflow bit.

```
b = 1111
2's complement => 0001

 1110
 0001
=====
01111
```

So it tells me that 14-15 is 15 (which is not surprising) but the overflow flag is set to 0.

Did i misunderstood the subtraction overflow bit, or is a `unsigned_cout xor sub` missing?

My VHDL-Code:

---

--full adder

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity fad is
    port(
        a,b,cin : in std_logic;
        o, cout: out std_logic);
end fad;



architecture behavior of fad is
begin
    o <= a xor b xor cin;
    cout <= (a and b)or (cin and (a xor b));
end behavior;
```

--adder-subtractor

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity add_sub is
    generic(N : natural := 4);
    port(
        a, b : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        sub : in std_logic;
        o : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        scout, ucout : out std_logic);

end add_sub;

architecture behavior of add_sub is
    signal carries : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
    signal bXorSub : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    component fad is
        port( a, b, cin : in std_logic;
                o, cout : out std_logic
        );
    end component;
begin
    carries(0) <= sub;
    subtraction: for i in 0 to N-1 generate
        bXorSub(i) <= b(i) xor sub; 
    end generate subtraction;

    RCA: for i in 0 to N-1 generate
        fadN: fad port map( 
            a => a(i), 
            b => bXorSub(i), 
            cin => carries(i),
            o => o(i), 
            cout => carries(i+1));
    end generate RCA;
    ucout <= carries(N);
    scout <= carries(N) xor carries(N-1);
end behavior;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have any code that goes along with this?  You've kept this description pretty abstract, but your very last sentence implies that you already have some programming code doing most of this.  If you can share it in your question, it would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i slept and now evrything is much clearer ;-)

After an **unsigned** subtraction the carry has to be '1' otherwise there is an overflow, an here is why.

The ripple carry adder consists of more (here 4) full adders. So we are never really subtracting. However in **signed** addition, we can calculate for exampe `4 + (-1)`.

With **unsigned** numers i can't represent a negative number. So in fact, i simply can't calculate `4 - 1`. I dont have any subtractor and i can't represent a negatie number.

So how can i perform such an operation. Because it clearly works. 4 - 1 = 3 (0100 - 0001 = 0011).

The only way, to decrease an **unsigned** number with only an adder, is to overflow it. The fact, that we can't represent all positive numbers is the solution (with 4 bit is the **unsigned** maximum 15).

For example we calculate 15 - 15 with 4 bit **unsigned** numbers. 15 - 15 is 0. So what do we add on "1111" to get "0000"? Simply just a "0001", which ist the Two's complement of 15. We rember:

```
2's complement = invert the number and add 1
"1111" => "0000"
"0000" + "0001" = "0001".
```

And then we add this number on our 15.

```
 1111
 0001
=====
10000
```

And there, as you can see is the (right) overflow.

So the last carry-bit by an unsigned subtraction has to be set to '1' if the calculation was performed right. Otherwise, if it is '0', the subtracted number should be negative, wich an unsigned number can not represent.

Comment: It took me longer than I care to admit to read this and fully grasp it.  Well done on explaining this, thanks for putting in the time to explain it when you figured it out.  Signed vs. Unsigned subtraction and addition is something that confuses a lot of people and each time I do it I need to be careful.  I actually wrote a signed vs. unsigned tutorial on my webpage here: http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-signed-unsigned.html.  I need to reread my example to see if what you discovered is properly covered in my own...

Comment: I think your example was so different because you were looking specifically at the carry bits, which I usually do not care about.  The tools just handle that stuff for me :)

Comment: Well my goal is to implement a mips processor, but that will take a long time. It is my learning by doing project. My first milestone is the alu. But first i need those componets (adders, shifters, comparators, etc.). I could use the library solution, but this is not my aim. I really want to know and understand it in depth. And as you can see, some questions will rise, which usually nobody asks.